# Rails, turbolinks, and broken mouse scroll wheel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have an issue with the scroll wheel on the mouse not working after I click a link on a rails site that uses turbolinks.  I'm not certain turbolinks is the problem, but I suspect that it is.

If I refresh the page using F5, the scroll works.  If I click a link to go to another page, it breaks again.

Has anyone ever had this issue?

EDIT:  It seems the issue happens in Chrome (53), but not in IE11.

Comment: Do you have a specific Javascript code dealing with mouse click ?

Comment: Please be more specific in the question, and add the necessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had two javascript manifest files (one for homepage and one for the rest of my app).  The one for the rest of my app had `// require_tree .` which included the homepages's javascript manifest.

I removed the `// require_tree .` directive from the main javascript manifest and included all of my javascript files in separate directives.